# Image-map click events in zoomable image

Tags: c#, image, windows-phone-8

I've got a large zoomable* image (loaded once using canvas nested in a ViewportControl) and I want to implement the following functionality:

The image should have several clickable areas attached that move along the image when the user zooms in/out, pinch, moves around etc.
Think about an image of a map from which I should get click events from specific areas.
I haven't figured out whether these areas should be re-attached when the user zooms or if I could attach them once.

Any ideas?

*I used the pinch and zoom code from this sample: http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/wpapps/Image-Recipes-0c0b8fee

edit:

I'm trying to make a single temp button work using the DeltaScale property of the zoom functionality.

These are two main function:

```
void OnManipulationDelta(object sender, ManipulationDeltaEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.PinchManipulation != null)
            {
                e.Handled = true;

            if (!_pinching)
                {
                   _pinching = true;
                   Point center = e.PinchManipulation.Original.Center;
                   _relativeMidpoint = new Point(center.X / TestImage.ActualWidth, center.Y / TestImage.ActualHeight);

                    var xform = TestImage.TransformToVisual(viewport);
                    _screenMidpoint = xform.Transform(center);
                 }

                 _scale = _originalScale * e.PinchManipulation.CumulativeScale;

                 // sample double variables for storing the changes of scaling          
                 // initial values of mytop & myleft are the initial actual spot of tempbtn on the image

                 mytop = e.PinchManipulation.DeltaScale * mytop;
                 myleft = e.PinchManipulation.DeltaScale * myleft;

                 CoerceScale(false);
                 ResizeImage(false);
            }
            else if (_pinching)
            {
                _pinching = false;
                _originalScale = _scale = _coercedScale;
            }
        }

        void OnManipulationCompleted(object sender, ManipulationCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
            _pinching = false;
            _scale = _coercedScale;

            Canvas.SetTop(tempbtn, mytop);
            Canvas.SetLeft(tempbtn, myleft);
       }
```

The resizing function for the main image in the background:

```
void ResizeImage(bool center)
        {
            if (_coercedScale != 0 && _bitmap != null)
            {
                double newWidth = canvas.Width = Math.Round(_bitmap.PixelWidth * _coercedScale);
                double newHeight = canvas.Height = Math.Round(_bitmap.PixelHeight * _coercedScale);

                xform.ScaleX = xform.ScaleY = _coercedScale;

                viewport.Bounds = new Rect(0, 0, newWidth, newHeight);

                if (center)
                {
                    viewport.SetViewportOrigin(
                        new Point(
                            Math.Round((newWidth - viewport.ActualWidth) / 2),
                            Math.Round((newHeight - viewport.ActualHeight) / 2)
                            ));
                }
                else
                {
                    Point newImgMid = new Point(newWidth * _relativeMidpoint.X, newHeight * _relativeMidpoint.Y);
                    Point origin = new Point(newImgMid.X - _screenMidpoint.X, newImgMid.Y - _screenMidpoint.Y);
                    viewport.SetViewportOrigin(origin);
                }
            }
        }
```

The problem is that my button always stands a little bit (around 10px, gets more as I zoom) to the top & left of the actual place I want it positioned. Something causes this deviation but I can't find out where's the problem. Any guesses/suggestions?

Comment: What have you tried so far? What went wrong? Please provide *your* code snippet that is not working for us to help you.

Comment: I added the code. Any help would be appreciated.